# Error when trying to connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, networkcredentials

I'm trying to connect to our online TFS. This is what I currently have:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(textBox_Username.Text, 
    textBox_password.Password);
Uri TFSurl = new Uri("https://myCompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
TfsConfigurationServer tfs = new TfsConfigurationServer(TFSurl, cred);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

This throws me :

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://actacom.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.

The Credentials entered are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx), it has a sample code on how to do it. I've tried it with my VSO account and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The blog helped me out.
For other people, here is the working code.

```
 NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
                textBox_Username.Text,
                textBox_password.Password);
                BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
                TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
                tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

                TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                    new Uri("https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"),
                    tfsCred);

                tpc.Authenticate();
```